# Title of menu not showing in actionbar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, icons, title

While adding item in menu title with image, then it will show only image/icon, not title. But i want both icon and title.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_reload"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_reload"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this attribute '**always|withText**'
It will work if there is sufficient room, otherwise it will only place icon. You can test it on your phone with rotation.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_reload"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_reload"
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
android:title="Refresh"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you Need to add tools:context="your class" to menu tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".activities.BaseActivity">


   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
       android:icon="@drawable/three"
       android:title="action_notification"
       app:showAsAction="always">
       <menu>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/profile"
               android:icon="@drawable/profile"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="PROFILE" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/c"
               android:icon="@drawable/correct_tick"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="COMPLETED TRIPS" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/app"
               android:icon="@drawable/report_issue"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="REPORT ISSUES" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/r"
               android:icon="@drawable/correct_tick"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="REACHED CENTER" />


           <item
               android:id="@+id/pdf"
               android:icon="@drawable/pdf_image"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="BAG INFO" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/l"
               android:icon="@drawable/logout"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="LOGOUT" />
       </menu>
   </item>


</menu>



     @Override 
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
         menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(3).setVisible(false);
         menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(4).setVisible(true);
         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         }
```

you shold write tool:context to menu tag then run you will get icons to your text